# Get current taxonomy post count

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

Is there a way to get the current taxonomy (category or tag) post count? The code i'm having is only for category

```
<?php 
    $cat = get_query_var( 'cat' );
    $categories = get_categories( 'include='.$cat );
    if ( $categories ) { 
        foreach( $categories as $category ) { 
            echo '' . $category->count;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Do you want the post count of a **category** or of a **term** of that category? That's to say, you want the count of all the posts with `Category X`, or the count of all the posts with ANY category (`Category X` or `Category Y` or `Category Z`)?

Comment: Hi MikO, thanks for the reply. I want the retrieve the post count for the current tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can do something like this:

```
// Set the name of your Taxonomy or get it as you're currently doing
// It can be category, tag or custom taxonomy name
$taxonomy = "your_taxonomy"; 

$total_count = 0;

// Get all the terms in your Taxonomy and add the count for each term
foreach ( get_terms( $taxonomy ) as $term ) {
    $total_count += (int) $term->count;
}

echo $total_count;
```

This will give you the count of all the posts that have assigned ANY term in the Taxonomy `your_taxonomy`, which I understand is what you want...